# Flickering ImageView When Dropped

Tags: android

I'm attempting to drag and drop an ImageView to specific coordinates.  It moves as I expect, but on Drop the image produces a single flicker for a split second.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is not my only attempt to eliminate the flicker.  I've tried different layouts, using LayoutParams to set the ImageView's location, using ConstraintSet to set location in a ConstraintLayout, using and removing invalidate().  All move the ImageView okay, all result in this flicker:

[image: Example of the flicker]

(all drops produce the flicker...some weren't captured)

I feel like I don't understand the way the images are drawn or redrawn on the screen maybe?

I'm overlooking something or there is something I don't understand.  I'd appreciate any insight.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.home_image_view);
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) iv.getParent();

    iv.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    constraintLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
}

private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    v);
            v.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, v, View.DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE);

            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                view.setX(event.getX() - (view.getWidth()/2));
                view.setY(event.getY() - (view.getHeight()/2));
                view.invalidate();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it help if `view.invalidate();` was removed from `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` switch case?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Aaron.  Removing `view.invalidate()` does not remove the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on this for a while.  I think the `DragShadowBuilder` was causing the issue...or at least the way I was using it.

My solution was to eliminate it from the code and change the view's position by using `view.setLayoutParams()` to update its margins on touch events.

No more flicker.